# How do I get the selected option to be shared with the original calling php page from an included page?

Tags: php, html, session

I have three documents that are being used to display one page.  One php and two included html documents like this:

1:  The user is on the create new user html page which is included in the new user php page.

2:  The new user html page calls another html page which is the select list html page.

3:  Finally I want to access the session variable  $_SESSION["Country"] on the landing page after the form is submitted.

Since the include statements are daisy chained two calls deep, how do I get the selected option to be shared with the original calling php page?

When I view page source I see the ...select name="Country" ... but I can't seem to access it in a session variable after I post the form.

Here I have a php page called NewUser.php

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  ?>
 <?php

   if (isset($_POST['submit']))
   {

// Process the form
// Process validations

    if (empty($errors))
    {

    // Perform Create

    $userName = ($_POST["userName"]);
    $password = ($_POST["password"]);
    $country = ($_POST["Country"]); //here is where I need access to $country

    // Password encription done here

    $query = "INSERT INTO myTable(userName,password,country)  VALUES('{$userName}', '{$password}','{$country}')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if ($result)
        {

        // Success

        $_SESSION["message"] = "User created.";
        $_SESSION["Country"] = $country;
        $_SESSION["username"] = $userName;
        $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
        }
      else
        {

        // Failure

        $_SESSION["message"] = "User creation failed.";
        }
     }
   }
  else
    {
  }

 ?>

 <?php
 $layout_context = "admin"; ?>

 <?php
 include ("newUser.html");
  ?> //Here I include the newUser.html file.  The the newUser.html includes the select list html file.
```

This is html doc that is built as just a list.  I built it this way in case I want to re-use the list.

This is html doc that is built as just a list.  I built it this way in case I want to re-use the list.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <?php
 session_start(); ?>

<title>Select</title>

// jquery to handle select list goes here

 </script>


 </head>
 <body>

  <select name="Country" id="country-selector" autofocus="autofocus"  autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option>

  // ...more options

   <option value="Åland Islands" data-alternative-spellings="AX Aaland Aland" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Åland Islands</option>

   <option value="Zimbabwe" data-alternative-spellings="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
   </select>


  </body>
 </html>
```

Then here is the html file that calls the list and do the form post.  The list is indluced here.

```
 <!doctype html>

 <head>
 <?php session_start(); ?>

 </head>
 <body>

    <form action="newUser.php" method ="post">  

    Counntry:
        <?php
```

include ("countrySelect/index.html");

// Here is where the included contrySelect.html happens

```
 ?>
    <p>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create User" />
    </p>
    </form>
      </div>
  </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling session_start twice. Don't do that. You only need to call it once in the outer-most file.

Comment: Got it...yes I caught that error.  Still not setting the session variable however.